# What is and isn't allowed within the callback (interrupt) subroutine for a GPIO state transition (perl, RPi::WiringPi, Raspberry pi, Raspbian)

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use GPIO pins on a Pi to interface some buttons which my software will then respond to. This is to add some controls to an existing Perl application, so my new work is also in Perl.

Really simple prototype hardware and software work; I configure the pin to input and pull-up mode (and wire it so pushing the button grounds the pin), and establish an interrupt routine, and in fact when I push the button the interrupt routine is called. So I might actually have the various packages and modules installed correctly, at least. (Contact bouncing is observed; I'll handle that in software eventually.)

When I try to take it up a level, though, I run into weird troubles. I've tried many things, which have failed in different ways. What I'm looking for here is some additional information about what sorts of things I am allowed to do in the interrupt function (set by $pin->set_interrupt('main::function_name')). That's called an "interrupt function", as well as a "callback". I doubt it's really running at hardware interrupt level (don't think Linux even supports user interrupt handlers!), but generally in that kind of callback there are hard rules, or at least very strong recommendations, about what you can and can't do there and what you should defer to later.

But none of the docs I can find (certainly not the basic CPAN docs or perldoc on the modules as loaded) really tell me much about the constraints.

For example, I find that calls to Log4Perl loggers work early in the interrupt function but not late :-). I suspect they're a bad idea within the interrupt function and one thing I tried happened to get lucky, but I could be wrong and there's no documentation about what's allowed and what isn't.

There's some suggestion that the interrupt function may run in another thread (but that's from the underlying WiringPi library not the Perl wrapper, and I found it in relation to functions not wrapped by the Perl wrapper, so maybe not).  My app isn't loading the threading library (I've been avoiding it; perl threading is "discouraged" officially), but maybe something I'm using in my more complicated application is (my main app that I intend to integrate this with uses MCE, which uses either threading or multiple forked processes; but my prototype I'm having trouble with is simpler and doesn't).

I'm also using Class::Tiny; I seem to be able to call class methods in the interrupt function, but it gets weird after a while. I'm avoiding it as much as possible currently.

Usually what you want to do is, in the interrupt function, note that the interrupt occurred, and then queue up the event to process in your main event loop, and do something perhaps to unblock that loop (like say signal a condvar that the loop waits on).  But no idea if the MCE::Shared::Condvar can safely be accessed in the interrupt function.

Is there more info on what is and isn't allowed in the interrupt function somewhere?  Are there more complex examples of code (that doesn't just print something in the interrupt function) out there?

Comment: What module does the `set_interrupt` function come from?

Comment: Sorry I missed that; it' from RPi:Pin (part of RPi::WiringPi)

Comment: Interrupts are designed to be as small and as short as possible. They are typically only used to set a flag or turn a pin HIGH/LOW. They are not meant to run a bunch of code. You do that in the main application. I am the author of `RPi::WiringPi`, and everything surrounding it. Can you update your post with some example code so I can see what you're doing?

Comment: Also, the threads I speak of in the docs are C threads, and they are handled by the underlying `wiringPi` library, which is wrapped by `WiringPi::API`, which is used heavily by `RPi::WiringPi` and many of its related distributions/modules. I will update the docs to specify that interrupts should be as short as possible, but I would like to see what you're trying to do, and tomorrow I will do some testing and investigation.

Comment: I've written actual hardware interrupt code back to 1970 I think, I'm trying to be careful about keeping the interrupt short. What I'm trying to avoid, though,is setting a flag in the interrupt and then polling the flag in the main code -- the whole point of the interrupt is to reduce latency in responding to the condition, after all, and polling adds latency.  When I tried *reading* a pin in the interrupt, it crashed immediately, I had decided I couldn't do that; is writing different? Or was that somehow an anomalous result?

Comment: I've made some progress on my own -- what I seem to have working now is enqueueing an entry in an MCE::Shared::Queue in the interrupt routine, and reading that queue elsewhere (an MCE::Child task; these are implemented as separate processes on Raspbian). (This represents progress since I posted my original query, too.)

Comment: I'm having modest success; got queuing to an MCE::Shared::Queue working in the interrupt function (and then dequeuing elsewhere).  I think it was with MCE::Queue that it failed for me before (and why those two both exist is a question I really don't want to be responsible for answering). It's looking like a win, and I'm not curious enough about *exactly* what I was doing wrong before to spend much time pursuing it. 

But, if you would happen to look at a post I'm about to make on trying to destroy and re-create a pin object....